# parse4cn1 callback usage example

Tags: callback, codenameone, parse4cn1

I have been using the new parse4cn1 and I must say its been pleasant, until I tried to use the signUpcallback and logincallback to direct users in my app to the "welcome" form after successful sign up or login. All I tried didn't work. So please I would like to see some working examples of parse4cn1 callback and if possible codename one callbacks in general.Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Good to hear that you find `parse4cn1` useful!

There aren't any callback examples because `parse4cn1` does not (yet) support asynchronous calls. This is not because of any technical limitations and should be straightforward to implement.

Support for callbacks isn't planned yet but you're free to give it a shot and I'll be glad to merge your PR (in that case please be sure to first check the [guidelines for contributing](https://github.com/sidiabale/parse4cn1#contributing)).